# How do I know if I should write a paper or an essay instead of a post on Facebook or a personal blog?

Tags: publications, social-media

I find it difficult to put in words what I observe. However, I will do my best to describe my confusion clearly, although if I could truly describe it clearly, probably I would have already found the answer. So, any help from you is appreciated.

It has been a long on-going dilemma in my mind that I unfortunately can't resolve myself. Nowadays, people tend to write their thoughts a lot on different social media. Although most of them are lack of surrounding discussion, some of the posts might be really outstanding with correct logical inferences. From another side, I constantly stumble upon popular scientists, philosophers who wrote an essay or paper on specific topic and it attracted a lot of attention in scientific and/or academic world. Take as an example one of my most recent findings - "Tragedy of Commons" by Garrett Hardin. He argues that there is no technological solution against overpopulation and describes, to me obvious, problem with common goods - people tend to overuse freely available resources of nature. Now, except just reference section, the whole essay and the point he is making looks to me kind of trivial that nowadays people who share same opinion discuss it over glass of beer. Does it mean that people who are writing similar thoughts on Facebook instead of writing an academic paper or not writing at all are missing an opportunity to contribute to the general knowledge of humankind? If not, what makes this essay so popular when it is written by someone like Garrett and not when by a bypassing stranger with the same thoughts? Is it a style of writing or reputation of the author? Why is it that truly great discourse will just dissolve in the noise of social media posts and not be cited anywhere?

Another example is rather about mindset. The wikipedia page about Hans Kelsen says he was jurist, legal philosopher and political philosopher. Later,

> Kelsen met Sigmund Freud and his circle, and wrote on the subject of social psychology and sociology

It could be my insecurity and doubt in myself. Still I want to understand. Is it truly normal for someone from one discipline to write a paper in another discipline just because that person got some ideas to share? Because it makes me wonder how much thoughts I could have written down and perhaps published if that is something acceptable. I am sure everyone once in a while gets ideas where they debate some statements in their mind. Does it mean we should go and write a paper even though we are not experts in that field yet our thoughts are logically valid? Now back to social media, in fact, this is how I believe people write their posts there. As soon as some more or less valid arguments come to the mind of people, they rush to post it on social media. Should they have considered to write an essay out of these thoughts and publish? If yes or no, then why?

As a last point, I will mention that there are even debates between scientists in a written and published form. For example, Manny Lehman replies to Lee Osterweil in the paper that he named as "Response To An ICSE9 Keynote Address By Lee Osterweil". I am sure there are other popular examples from physics and other disciplines. My question is why wouldn't they just discuss it via mail or in-person, or via calls. If you advocate that people writing meaningful posts on social media should also consider writing papers, does it mean that commenters also should consider writing their answers as papers instead of comments? We all have seen heated debates under some post on Facebook. What qualifies a reply to some paper as a separate "response paper"?

So all of these sub-questions can be summarized as one question "How do I know if my thoughts qualify as a paper/essay, especially philosophical discussions or are they just one more idea for a post on Facebook that brings no value to academic world or whatever world it is for which Garrett Hardin wrote his "Tragedy of Commons" and Hans Kelsen wrote on the subject of psychology while being a jurist?"

Sorry for the long question but I could not put it elsehow to make it more clear.

Comment: These examples are from decades ago. There were different norms for publishing at that time. Do you have a more recent example that illustrates your question?

Comment: " Now, except just reference section, the whole essay and the point he is making looks to me kind of trivial that nowadays people who share same opinion discuss it over glass of beer." Exactly: 52 years ago it required a publication peer reviewed by other academic to discuss these topics, because discussing that over a glass of beer would have meant "discussing with a lunatic about crazy topics". 
Social media & co reader have an attention span of 5 seconds: it is not possible to discuss anything, they are just reacting to some written stimulus.

Comment: @Dawn, unfortunately no and surprisingly enough only such old papers raise this type of questions in me. Do you know if there is any material about norms for publishing? It will be interesting to read how norms changed over the time. I think this can explain a lot to me and resolve confusions

Comment: @EarlGrey, "Social media & co reader have an attention span of 5 seconds" - I think it is a good factor to consider on my way of understanding if I should write a paper. I do not want to look silly in the eyes of other scientists by them thinking "this could have been a facebook post, not an article"

Comment: At worst, the feedback you will get from other scientists is "you should update yourself to the state of art on topic X" which is not a moral evaluation, simply an assessment of your knowledge at the current point in time and it is a quite common feedback. It simply states the necessity for you "to stand on the shoulder of giants". On the other hand, you may want to confute some past ideas: if the idea is new, it means you have to discuss state of art, if the idea is old, you will likely find someone that already discussed its confutation, start from there.

Comment: "These examples are from decades ago. There were different norms for publishing at that time". @Dawn, I found out there is a type of papers called "Position paper" which I think is what I was looking for as an answer. This type of papers contains opinions and views on some matter with a logical explanation why it is the case. So, I think if authors of those old articles lived today, they would still publish their thoughts in form of a position paper.

Comment: Well, position papers exist, but likely Hardin would have published this as a theoretical political science article with more formal game theory in it. It is super-simple game theory that he just chose to show without math.

Comment: @Dawn, does it mean one can publish articles of the same style, it just takes the right field and journal to submit the article to? Because the whole article of Hardin is more like an opinion justified by arguments

Comment: No , it just means that game theory was newer and had not been applied to such situations in those early years. There is a lot of opinion there (some very controversial and somewhat racist, if I remember), but if you read carefully he does set out a game theoretic argument early in the piece.

Comment: @Dawn, imagine I think that one of the reasons why bugs appear in the software is because most of the developers are not familiar with formal math. Would that constitute a good article and how should I approach writing such an article if there is no statistics of how much developers actually know math? Or is it something that one should not write an article about? Because definitely, it is a no-brainer to write this kind of an opinion on Facebook. But how legit is this topic for an article?

Comment: No, this would not be a good article because you could easily add some actual empirical evidence. You could survey developers about their familiarity with formal math or empirically compare the code of those who do and do not have formal math training or catalog the math curricula of educational programs that train developers. When the bar to the next level of research is very low I don’t support writing such an article.

Comment: @Dawn, thank you very much for your thoughts. Then, it appears to me that my thoughts supported by valid arguments are totally worthless to share anyway unless I conduct a survey which could still be biased.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127568/discussion-between-turkhan-badalov-and-dawn).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much reason to think in terms of "X instead of Y". Many prominent scientists are active both in academic publishing and in social media and/or write for general public. It is perfectly reasonable to discuss matters both in press and "over a glass of beer" (i.e., on Facebook).

The largest difference for you would probably be the expectations of most academic publishers. You are not really supposed to "share your thoughts" in a scientific paper. You are supposed to extend knowledge in a somewhat reliable manner by starting with some existing knowledge and enriching it (in most cases) by means of data analysis and experiments.

If you understand very well what is generally known and what is generally unknown, and you can demonstrably make a reliable step forward, you can write a paper about it. Otherwise consider it an informal chat, which can of course be a productive pastime as well.

Comment: "If you understand very well what is generally known and what is generally unknown" - do you think this comes only from experience or is there any other way I can read about what is generally unknown in the field? Obviously, I am not going to compete solving "Millenials problems" but I still want to make my small contributions into some subject

Comment: Discuss in online communities. Read Wikipedia endnotes. Search in Google Scholar, read what you find interesting (esp. with high number of citations), then check works these papers cite and papers citing the paper you read. Find what are major journals in the field of your interest and see what kind of works they generally publish and how they are composed. Might sound like a steep hill, but the point of the journals is to publish "new knowledge" rather than just ideas that make sense.